# Oracle procedure to update multiple values in single instance

Tags: oracle

Is there a procedure I can run to search all tables to see to search a particular column? I need to update a particular string present in that column in all tables whereever applicable. There are too many tables to open each one and do a find on the value(s) I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you find the tables which contain your columns:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME='your_column_name';
```

After that you can execute updates for each table that you have.

I didn't understand your question completely, so I hope this helps you ;)